# Text reply after watchOS notification is failing only when the corresponding app is installed on the watch

Tags: ios, notifications, watchkit, apple-watch, ios9.1

I have an iOS9 app with a watchKit 1.0 Extension. Most functionality is working fine. One of the main features of the app is a private messaging feature, which is also working great.

I'm using UIUserNotificationActionBehaviorTextInput for iOS9+ devices so that when a user receives a notification on their watch, they will be able to use the built in reply feature.

This works great, but only if the watchKit app is NOT installed on the watch. Users are able to reply to a notification on their watch with canned responses, or dictate a response with no problems. Note, this does NOT launch the watchKit app - it just uses the built-in reply functionality of the watch.

**When the watchKit app IS installed on the watch, the "Message" and "Dismiss" buttons appear as expected. But as soon as someone clicks the Message button, instead of being able to tap or dictate a response, it just immediately goes back to the watch face.**

It is 100% reproducible using two separate sets of an iPhone 6 running iOS9.1 and Apple Watch running watchOS 2.0.1. Since notifications can't be tested in the simulator, this is a very difficult problem to troubleshoot.

I could really use some guidance in what steps to take next.